# Python | How to improve my regex which validates names?

Tags: python, regex, matching

I have a Python regex which validates names given by a user in a chatbot.

```
(?=.{2,100}$)[^\W\d_]{2,}(?:[-\s][^\W\d_]{2,})*
```

As you can see in the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/sd3a0N/1), it works great, but I have still problems for the following inputs:

- Mathias d'Arras
- Mike O'Neal
- Peter.
- Peter?
- Peter!
- Boby-Dick.
- Boby-Dick?
- Boby-Dick!

As you can see, I want my regex match even if the user types his name with a punctuation mark.
How would you improve the regex?

Comment: Try `^(?=.{2,100}$)[^\W\d_]+(?:[-' ][^\W\d_]+)*[.?!]?$`, see https://regex101.com/r/GSciL5/1

Comment: It does not work great at all -- the entire section from `Peter` until `Martin Luther King Jr.` is matched as a single name.

Comment: And you want it to match `Peter.` but not `Peter...`, and `Peter?` but not `Peter?!?`. What is the use case for that?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew: This looks very good! Thank you very much. Many chatbot users  type name + punctuation mark. I wanted my regex to match this, because this is a valid input in my chatbot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To enhance the current pattern you can replace `{2,}` limiting quantifiers with `+` to allow single char prefixes like `O'` or `d'` and add an optional `[.?!]?` pattern at the end:

```
^(?=.{2,100}$)[^\W\d_]+(?:[-' ][^\W\d_]+)*[.?!]?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GSciL5/1). You may add more punctuation chars you want to allow at the end of the name into the character class (remember to escape `^`, `]`, `-` and `\` inside square brackets).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.{2,100}$)` - there must be two to 100 chars in the string
- `[^\W\d_]+` - one or more letters
- `(?:[-' ][^\W\d_]+)*` - zero or more occurrences of a space, `'` or `-` followed with one or more letters
- `[.?!]?` - an optional `?`, `!`, `.`
- `$` - end of string.